# A question about window.open and cookie

Tags: javascript, browser, cookies

Say I have two apps, **www.test.com** and **sub.test.com**, now in **sub.test.com**, I create a window to load **www.test.com** with codes like :

```
window.open('www.test.com');
```

So the window just popup and load **www.test.com** successfully.
Then I set a cookie in **sub.test.com**, say **"uname=wong2;domain=.test.com"**, I've learned that with set to `domain=.test.com`, all sites with domain **test.com**(such as **www.test.com**, **aaa.test.com**, **test.com**) can read the cookie.

But when I try to load the cookie from the window that just popup with **www.test.com**, it can't get it.

Then I found that if I don't use **window.open** but directly open **www.test.com** in browser, it works.

So is there some restrictions on **window.open** and **cookie**?

Comment: Not that I have ever heard of. Did you set the path to "/" too? And are you using the same port numbers and protocol (http/https)

Comment: In which browser(s) does this problem occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check how you set the cookie:

```
var domain = 'test.com';
var expires = (function(days){
    date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return date.toUTCString();
})(5);
var name = 'myCookie';
var path = '/';
var value = 'foo';    

document.cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "; expires=" + expires + "; path='" + path + "'; domain=" + domain + ";";
```

Answer (score 0):

That is called cross domain and you cant set cookie in one domain and try to access that in different domain. Browsers wont allow doing this.**I think you can accomplish this using iframe or same origin policy or try using document.domain** I am not sure what you want to do exactly.

Comment: Cookies can cross domains if set properly to allow it.